# how to display form submit value without storing in db django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I am trying to make a Sign-up page  in django for a brand. I want the user register his/her brand on my web app but it will not store the information in db until the admin not accept it, but i don't know how can i do this

Model.py

```
class BrandRegister(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()
```

Comment: Not sure how you expect not to store it (in some way) before it is accepted. It should be stored (when submitted), but its status should be _awaiting-to-be-accepted_ (this can be implemented in number of ways). After it is approved by admin, change status.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it with a boolean field, for example adding an `active` boolean field(with default value in False), then when you list the brand registered, just filter by this boolean for the active ones. When you want to accept a brand, just put the boolean on True.

Comment: but it will be store in db when it is false

Comment: Yes, because it is the only way that someone else see it later and be able to accepted.

Comment: mean there is not way to without storing data i can accept

Comment: you can store data in a cookie/session, but I think that its better put it in a db to not loose the record.

Answer (score 0):

You want users to be able to register information, but not store it in a database; You also want an administrator to be able to check whether or not it is stored in a db. this interesting question.

1.The simplest thing to do, it may be against your question, but it works. Add a new field in `BrandRegister`

```py
class BrandRegister(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    owner_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    contact_no = models.BigIntegerField()
    is_accpet = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # this
```

Admin can choose to set is_accpet to True

2.Serialize BrandRegister Instance to a file, then Admin selects which ones to deserialize and stores them to DB.